# What is the meaning of the expression "that's all you had to say"?

Tags: grammar

In the movie *Pulp Fiction*, there is a scene where **Jules** talks on the phone with **Marcellus Wallace** because he needs help with getting rid of the body of **Marvin**.

Toward the end of the phone call, they say:

> **Marcellus**: You ain't got no problem, Jules. I'm on the m***** f*****. Go back in there and chill them n*****s out, and wait for the Wolf, who should be coming directly.
>   **Jules**: You're sending the Wolf?
>   **Marcellus**: You feel better, m***** f*****?
>   **Jules**: Sh*t, N***gro, **that's all you had to say.**

[Scene Link on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_IXzU-lnLU)

I thought of two possible meanings for that:

1.) Is that all you had to say? (sarcasm) It's like it's not good, but in fact, it is VERY GOOD!

2.) That's all you had to say. (from the beginning)

Which one is right?

Comment: He drops his voice at the end. That, and his demeanor, indicate no sarcasm. Also, I don't quite understand the difference between your #1 and #2. Anyway, one sentence does not a context make.

Comment: Can't tell without more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have provided the link **to the script.**

> ```
>                                  MARSELLUS
>                      You ain't got no problems, Jules. 
>                      I'm on the mother****r. Go back in 
>                      there, chill them niggers out and 
>                      wait for The Wolf, who should be 
>                      comin' directly.
>
>                                  JULES
>                      You sendin' The Wolf?
>
>                                  MARSELLUS
>                      Feel better?
>
>                                  JULES
>                      Sh*t N****, that's all you had to 
>                      say.
> ```
>
> ["PULP FICTION" By, Quentin Tarantino & Roger Avary](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/pulp_fiction.html)

Jules says:

**that's all you had to say** : this is enough to calm me down; I know what an expert The Woolf is for making bodies to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It means that nothing else needed to be said, only that the Wolf was coming. Jules knows that the Wolf will handle the situation, so no other explanation was needed.